# Bake Texture with 3ds Max for OpenGl

Tags: opengl-es, textures, 3dsmax, 3d-modelling, uv-mapping

I have a problem with render to texture. The texture is mapped on each polygon instead to the whole object. Here in the [Qualcomm Forum](https://ar.qualcomm.com:443/arforums/showthread.php?t=365&referrerid=11163) the problem described in detail again from User andreasv. Can you help me? I need to bake the texture with another program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem in a engine I work with, for me I solved it by checking the uvw channel, on my baked objects it set it to channel 3, but on export it exported channel 1, give it a try, check the id in the faces, and in your material (the bitmap in the material you apply).
Try and set them both to using channel 1.